# Why do left-aligned tables in an email stack on the Android Gmail App when they contain full width images?

Tags: android, html, css, email, gmail

I'm aware the Android Gmail App does not allow media queries so should show the desktop version of the e-mail.

For the most part it does, however there is one section that should sit side-by-side and for some reason on the Android Gmail app, it stacks, it appears to be due to the image being the same width as the table, because it works fine if there is just text in each left-aligned table.
I'm wondering if anyone else has come across this issue and found a solution?

The only solution I've come across so far is to reduce the width of the image, which then leaves a gap to the right of the image.

Code below:

```
<table class="mobile_wrapper" bgcolor="#000000" border="0" width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#000000; width:640px;">
                <tr>
                  <td>    
                    <table align="left" class="mobile_wrapper" bgcolor="#000000" border="0" width="320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#000000;width:320px;"> 
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/320x389" alt="image" width="100%" height="389" border="0" align="top" class="mobile_image" style="display:block;" /> 
                         </td>
                       </tr>  
                   </table>
                  <table align="left" class="mobile_wrapper" bgcolor="#000000" border="0" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#000000;width:320px;"> 
                       <tr>
                         <td>
                           <img src="https://placehold.it/320x389" alt="image" width="100%" height="389" border="0" align="top" class="mobile_image" style="display:block;" />
                         </td>
                       </tr>
                 </table>
               </td>
             </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this was down-voted - but for anyone else that has this issue it was actually a simple fix - I think it's to do with Gmail's auto-sizing.

The way to get around it is to ensure the image has a width of 100% within a table with a fixed width - that way if the table shrinks - the image will shrink with it.
I almost had it - but for some reason had a 50% width on the second left-aligned table.